# Saving VS Code settings in public gist

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

To sync my VS Code settings across multiple devices, I found [Shan Khan's](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shan.code-settings-sync) extension that works by saving settings in a GitHub gist. I wanna know if it is safe to save my settings in a public gist or not? Is there an alternative way for doing so? What's included in the gist?

Comment: gist is just a code sharing platform like any other, just like codepen etc but its by github and has all the git features to it like revisions etc. As long as you save your settings on a private gist no one can see it and even if you host your settings on a public one there is no security or privacy risk .

Comment: What's included in the file?

Comment: All the data in your `settings.json` file that is where the whole of VSCode and the extensions are configured.